# Can background images in Word be build into paragraph styles?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to replicate the "background-image" CSS functionality in a Word style?

I'd like to create a icon-ized callout box -- so a box that is set-off from the main flow of text, and has an icon in the upper left corner.  In CSS, I could do this by combining margins, padding, and background images.

Can I do this in Word?  I'd like a paragraph style that did all that (I can do this part), and also placed the icon, as a background or inline (I can't seem to do this part).